# Set System Time programmatically

Tags: c++-winrt

Is it possible to set the system date and time from an uwp app?
I was just trying a simple way. But this throws an error.

```
void winrt::Calender::implementation::MainPage::datePicker_DateChanged(winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::CalendarDatePicker const& sender, winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::CalendarDatePickerDateChangedEventArgs const& args)
{
    Windows::System::DateTimeSettings::SetSystemDateTime(args.NewDate().GetDateTime());
}

WinRT originate error - 0x80004001 : 'Not implemented'.
```

Comment: This one is awkward. It was initially introduced in the IoT Extension SDK, and later (17763 I think) moved into the Windows Universal SDK. Which target version are you targeting?

Comment: @IInspectable 10.0.19041.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This API is only implemented for IoT devices and requires the `systemManagement` capability.

Setting the system time requires administrator rights on Desktop in any case, so this is not something a UWP can generally do.

> If you want to know why system time is protected in this way, see [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/change-the-system-time)